# D'où vient l'expression « n'en déplaise à... » ?

Tags: expressions, origine-ou-raison, double-négation

Un ami m'a interrogé sur le paradoxe apparent entre le sens de cette expression et les mots qui la composent. En effet, elle contient en quelque sorte une double négation, et mon ami me faisait remarquer que, les négations ôtées, on avait l'air de dire en fait le contraire de ce qu'on entend habituellement par cette expression (car c'est précisément à des personnes à qui la chose en question ne plait *pas*, selon le contexte, qu'on fait référence).

Pour essayer d'être plus clair avec un exemple :

> N'en déplaise à mon adversaire, le point est pour moi.

La seule manière que j'ai trouvée pour en expliquer le sens, c'est de supposer que c'est la contraction d'une expression de courtoisie, originalement plus longue mais qu'on aura raccourci progressivement.

La version plus longue pourrait ressembler à :

> *[Je prie qu'il]* N'en déplaise *[pas]* à mon adversaire, *[mais il faut bien constater que]* le point est pour moi.

C'est ma supposition de départ, mais j'avoue ne pas avoir trouvé grand chose sur le sujet. Des idées allant dans ce sens ? dans un autre sens ?

Comment: Que faisiez-vous au temps chaud ?

Comment: Peut-être si ce “ne” s’agit d’un “ne explétif” (avec « déplaire » en subjonctif), elle perdrait un peu de la notion double négation : « bien qu’il ne [’en] déplaise à mon adversaire, le point est pour moi ».

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« N'en déplaise à ... » comme « Ne vous déplaise / Ne vous en déplaise » signifie « Que cela ne lui/vous déplaise pas » que l'on peut rapprocher de « Sauf votre respect ».

La double négation me parait obligatoire car « En plaise à » n'aurait aucun sens, la formule accompagnant toujours un complément qui ne peut que déplaire à son destinataire.

La signification est donc ici:

> Que sa perte ne déplaise pas à mon adversaire mais le point est pour moi.

La tournure est le plus souvent ironique :

> Que cela plaise ou non à mon adversaire, le point est pour moi.

Comment: Effectivement, la formulation *Que cela ne lui déplaise* est un moyen terme entre l'expression initiale courte et ma version "explicitée" plus longue, et je n'y avais pas pensé, merci ^^