# Why is there an « en » here?

Tags: grammaire

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtNRZCEfMUI, from 2:45:31-2:45:35, if I heard it right, Macron says « parce que la priorité de la politique, ne vous en déplaise Madame Le Pen ». Why is there an « en » here, my dictionary does not have an entry for « en déplaisir » like it does for « s'en aller » so I'm assuming the « en » refers to something but what?

Comment: The en refers to it: the preceding priorité de la politque. Look at jlliagre's answer:  (je souhaite) que ça ne vous déplaise pas . The ça is the preceding thought.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ***en*** is optional and ***déplaise*** is the third person subjunctive present of the verb *[**déplaire**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9plaire)* here, not a derivate of the noun ***déplaisir***.

Macron uses the set expression ***ne vous (en) déplaise*** which is a shorter form of the phrase:

> ***qu'il ne vous en déplaise***, i.e. *(je souhaite) que ça ne vous déplaise pas* (I hope you don't mind).

Nowadays, it is always used ironically and means:

> **whether it bothers you or not** / **like it or not**.

See also: [D'où vient l'expression « n'en déplaise à... » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13829)